# Which of the 4 Pathfinder Beginner Box pregens are best for a 2 or 3 player starter group?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, new-players, pathfinder-beginner-box

I'm planing to host my first RPG as a DM with some buddies, and we might be just two or three players and me as the DM. I bought the Pathfinder beginner box, which has a pre made adventure and four pre made characters: Fighter, Rogue, Cleric and Wizard, all with quite traditional builds.

If I don't get a full group of four players, then we have to choose which characters to use. Which of these are the most or least essential? All of the other players will be beginners, so it's a goal to give them a good introduction to roleplaying. I'm aware that there is no define or "right" answer, but I am hoping that there is a best combination of three out of the four roles that will make their first experience rewarding.

Comment: For 5e, but I think the answers still apply: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49954/im-dming-for-a-party-of-two-how-can-i-make-sure-my-players-have-classes-that-c - also a good example of how to ask a question like this; asking from people's experience is fine, but when you just ask for "reflections or advice" instead of an answer people immediately vote to close as too broad and/or opinion based.  See this meta question for more help... http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5758/why-was-my-question-closed-as-too-broad-unclear-or-opinion-based

Comment: @mxyzplk I would not say that the answers generally apply, as classes in D&D5e are (from my experience) broader than pathfinder classes in what they can do.

Answer (score 1):

The Fighter and The Rogue are no doubt the easiest and fastest classes to get into. There's no spells to prepare or memorize, plus the players get right into the action. They also both have very unique class skills to each other which compliment the other's weaknesses.

The third is up to the player, if they don't mind being a lot more passive/defensive in fights, they can go with Cleric. If they prefer to be more aggressive, Wizard might be the way to go.

Overall, I think the best start would be a Fighter and a Rogue, with a Cleric if there is a third player. Though remember that overall, just have fun!

Happy adventuring!

Comment: I feel like this is a pretty generic answer and does not account for the beginner box setting/adventure at all.  specifically there is no mention of who can wield that dragonbane longsword (or other loot), which is very likely required for any party to survive if they do not choose to simply flee.